# How to change CSS tab stop in Google Chrome Inspector (Developer tools)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I usually use chrome inspector to make changes in my web pages. At the end, I want to copy styles from the panel to my CSS file, to keep changes.

I use 4 space tabs in my codes, but when the code is copied, it is indented by 2 spaces, that makes it incompatible with whole document, and I have fix it every time.

Is there anyway to change this default tab stop in Chrome Inspector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Settings > Preferences > Sources, there's a combo for picking the 'Default indentation'.

[image: Indentation]

### Example:

1. Copy the code in the Styles tab

[image: Styles tab]

2. Paste it into your text editor

[image: Atom]

As you can see, there are 4 spaces characters shown.